Trouble creating a file in the Documents folder
I'm working on an Android app where I need to save logs to a file in the Documents folder on external storage. I'm using the Timber and Treessence libraries for logging.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
private val documents = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)

fun start() {
    val fileName = "${currentDate()}.log"
    val tree = FileLoggerTree.Builder()
        .withFileName(fileName)
        .withDir(documents)
        .appendToFile(true)
        .build()

    Timber.plant(tree)
}

Inside the builder, the directory is created with this code:
File(dir).apply {
    if (!isDirectory) {
        mkdirs()
    }
}

On my physical device running Android 13, the file is created correctly in the Documents folder. However, when I run the app on an emulator with Android 9 (API 28), I get the following error:
NoSuchFileException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/31_07_2024.log.0.lck

My question is: How can I properly create a file in the Documents folder on devices running API 23 to 34?

For older devices, you need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, including requesting it at runtime. FWIW, I strongly discourage supporting as far back as API Level 23 (Android 6.0 IIRC). That is nearly a decade old and is riddled with security flaws that will never be fixed at this point.

@CommonsWare thanks. It was helpful. But now I have another problem: I don't see my file in File Explorer. I see it exists in Android Studio's Device Explorer in directory: storage/emulated/0/Documents. I need to browse my file outside the app.
